Why does setting rankdir=LR order nodes top-to-bottom?
After several hacky/copy-paste graphviz diagrams, I'm making at attempt at understanding the dot language in earnest, and I have a very basic question.
The following dot code:
digraph G
{
    subgraph cluster_obj
    {
        A [label="A"]
        B [label="B"]
    }
} 

...renders like this:

I understand, from the graphviz documentation, that rankdir=LR is only to be used at the graph level, and is meant for the purpose of arranging graphs left-to-right (I assume this means ordering subgraphs left-to-right.
Why, then, does adding rankdir=LR to the above simple graph result in the nodes within a subgraph being arranged top-to-bottom?
digraph G
{
    rankdir=LR
    subgraph cluster_obj
    {
        A [label="A"]
        B [label="B"]
    }
} 


I've been reading on graphviz/dot language from the graphviz.org official documentation, various Stack Overflow articles, and whatever hits web searches lead me to, but I haven't yet formed a comprehensive working knowledge of how to create and arrange diagrams to will. This question is inspired by this Stack Overflow answer, which seems to implicitly rely on rankdir=LR for the desired arrangements of its nodes 2 and 3 (which is crucial to the OP's question) -- but in that answer, as in the examples in this question, I don't see a pattern that reveals when and why nodes and subgraphs are arranged left-to-right vs. top-to-bottom.

Good question.  Your assumption that rankdir's purpose is for ordering subgraphs left-to-right is incorrect.   Rankdir specifies the ranking direction.  (sorry for the circular definition, keep reading)
The key concept here is rank - placing nodes into rows (or columns if rankdir=LR or RL).  Except for a special case or two, ranking is performed based on edges.  A head node is place on a greater rank that the tail node.  Think about a diagram of a tree structure - the tail and head will be on different ranks.
Your examples have no edges (perfectly legal), so all the nodes are placed on the same rank.
For more in-depth info see https://graphviz.org/pdf/dotguide.pdf
p.s. note that ranking only applies to the dot layout engine.  The other Graphviz engines work based on other models.

Thank you for this answer -- I need to digest it a little to fully grok it, but I wonder if I could ask you to flesh out one related detail in your answer, you note that rankdir has to do with "placing nodes into rows." According to the official documentation, rankdir is valid on graphs. Do you have any insight on why this is so? Since nodes can be elements of subgraphs, why is rankdir only accepted at the graph level, and not at the subgraph level? At my present level of understanding dot language, I still don't fully grasp how to control ranking at various granularities of the graph.

Best guess: it is a function of the overall algorithm. 1. do ranking 2. place nodes "left-to-right" on appropriate rank. 4. minimize edge crossing 4. draw edges.  Could one come up with another algorithm?  Sure (don't as me to do it).  But it would seem to be a major enhancement.  Again, think directed (tree-like) networks.
